# UILabel how to get label to autosize a name to a maximum width and truncate?

Tags: uilabel

So I've got this UILabel that I'd like to have it auto size to a maximum width, stop, then truncate. The reason for the autosize is that there is another label (date) that I'd like to be just to the right of this by a set amount of pixels (10px).

I've attempted to use a frame on the UILabel but that just statically sets the width,but that didn't work and I need this to auto size...

Screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to use size to fit for whenever the label is not too long, then "cut" it off when it's too long.  It's pretty much as simple as it sounds.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 96, 90, 16)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:label.frame.size.height];
label.text = @"Johnny Appleseed";
[label sizeToFit];
[self addSubview:label];

const int CUT_OFF_AT_X = 100;
float labelRight = label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width;
if (labelRight > CUT_OFF_AT_X) {
    label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, CUT_OFF_AT_X - label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.size.height);
}
labelRight = label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width;

UILabel *badge = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelRight, 96, 90, 16)];
badge.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
badge.font = label.font;
badge.text = @"LEVEL 90";
[badge sizeToFit];
[self addSubview:badge];
```

Comment: This is a great way to go about this, and on top of that I'd like to add that in the if statement adding the following auto re-sizes the text and prevents ellipsis to a certain point.

label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumScaleFactor = .5f;

Answer (score 0):

Great answer!  For swift 3:

```
if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact && ((lbl_FacilityName.text?.length ?? 0) > 15) {
        print("if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact and label larger than 15 chars ")

        //If label is too long cut the width off at the start of the segmented control -3 for padding
        lbl_FacilityName.frame = CGRect(x: lbl_FacilityName.frame.origin.x, y: lbl_FacilityName.frame.origin.y, width: ((segPatientSortControl.frame.origin.x - 3) - lbl_FacilityName.frame.origin.x), height: lbl_FacilityName.frame.size.height)
     }
```